# Moving two-state, prismatic joint in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, joint, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
My robot is a basic diff-drive vehicles, that has a lift on top (to transport a pallet). The lift is connected to a base by a prismatic joint (it moves along z axis ). Here is my question. How to make it move from "down position" to "up position" and inversely. I would like to write a plugin that is seen from ros (subscribe to a ROS topic) and accept two commands : up and down. The main problem is how to move the lift.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271468/moving-two-state,-prismatic-joint-in-gazebo/) by [michal089](https://answers.ros.org/users/32010/michal089/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-09-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there! Can you do a rostopic echo and check that the controllers are sending effort commands?
If they are sending them then you are on the right path, might want to check your PID gains because they could be so low that it doesn't overcome the weights of your prismatic link.

You can check how to tune the PIDs for gazebo in this tutorial:
http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0